# Passing method parameter to the start method of batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I have a below batch class where I am passing 100 account ids to the constructor and in the debug logs I can see 100 in constructor as a set size but in start method I can see 0, could someone please suggest

```
 public class batching implements database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    static set<id> accountIdSet = new set<Id>();
    public restCallout(set<id> accountIds) {

        accountIdSet = accountIds;
        System.debug('size from constructor '+accountIdSet.size());

    }

    public static database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('size from start method '+ accountIdSet.size());
        return database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ID In:accountIdSet ]); 
    }

    public static void execute(database.BatchableContext bc, list<sObject> Scope) {
        System.debug('Size from execute '+ Scope.size());

        for(Account act: (List<Account>)scope) {            
            makeACallout();
        }
    }
    public static void finish(database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }
```

Comment: be careful with callouts in batch execute() - there are limits to worry about (# callouts, total callout time) so you need to keep scope size well under 200

Answer (score 4):

The conventional way to write this is to pass the Account Ids in the constructor and not use any `static` declarations:

```
 public class Batching implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    public Batching(Set<Id> accountIdSet) {
        this.accountIdSet = accountIdSet;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('size from start method '+ accountIdSet.size());
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id
            FROM Account
            WHERE ID In :accountIdSet
        ]); 
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
        System.debug('Size from execute '+ scope.size());
        for (Account act: (List<Account>) scope) {            
            makeCallout(act);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }

    private void makeCallout(Account act) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It can then be used like this:

```
Integer batchSize = 100;
Set<Id> accountIdSet = ...
Database.executeBatch(new Batching(accountIdSet), batchSize);
```

There are other ways to pass values but a [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)):

> prepares the new object for use

so is a good way to go to stop users of the class invoking it before it is in the right state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this:-

```
set<id> accountIdSet{get;set;}
public restCallout(set<id> accountIds) {

    accountIdSet = accountIds;
    System.debug('size from constructor '+accountIdSet.size());
}
```

Automatic properties allow you to write more compact code that is easier to debug and maintain. 
It will make sure accountIdSet retain the value in start method.

### Update

Also, remove the static keyword from variable definition of accountIdSet.

Comment: Thank you for responding but it is still not working, I am getting null pointer exception in start method where I am checking the size of accountIdSet but in constructor I can see 100, please suggest

Comment: @gs650x, I have updated my answer